# Laravel: Configuring default mail host

Tags: laravel

I have module sending email to the administrator of the website.

Scenario: if the user done fill up all the text box then he / she submit it, automatically the administrator of website determine that there is new message.

The problem is, the administrator email look like this.
administrator@xxxxxxx.ca it gives error when the user click.

**ENV FILE:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.xxxxxx.ca
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.ca 
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.xxxxxxx.ca [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]

How to configure the host @gmail.com to  host xxxxxx.ca

Comment: I really don't understand the question but the error looks like the * administrator@xxxxxxx.ca* server doesn't have and STMP server or you have the wrong username/password

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when some changes have been made to files, specifically in `.env file`

Clear cache using artisan command

`php artisan config:clear`

Clear config

`php artisan cache:clear`

Restart your server

`sudo service apache2 restart`

More: Try clearing browsers cache & cookies. Hope that works